# Node.js: Variable scope behaves differently in Electron and non-Electron script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to make a command line version of one of my Electron apps as a Node.js script. To start, I copied over the code from my Electron app but it does not behave the same. As an example, here I have two modules that I created. When calling `webscraper.scrape()` in the Electron app the code executes as expected. However, when I call the function in the plain Node.js script it throws a `"database is not defined error"`. Testing with other variables it appears that no variables I define in `main.js` are accessible in any of my modules, which is the opposite of how it was in my Electron app.

Is this the expected behavior? How can I make my variables accessible by my modules? Is doing so bad practice, and if so how can I improve both my Electron and Nods.js scripts?

```
// main.js
var database = require('./src/database.js');
var webscraper = require('./src/webscraper.js');

database.init().then(()=> {
    webscraper.scrape();
});
```

```
// webscraper.js
exports.scrape = function() {
    // Find where we left off
    database.connection.query('SELECT `last_searched` FROM `post_index` WHERE `id` = 0', function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: In node.js, your `database` variable in main.js is ONLY available within the module scope of main.js where you imported it.  If you want it available in webscraper.js, then you need to import it there too.  Every module must import the things it needs.  This allows modules to explicitly name their dependencies, makes them easier to share or reuse and makes them easier to test.  This practice encourage, "good module design".    In your specific case, you may want/need to pass the `database` instance to your `scrape()` function so it can use the one you've already initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node.js, your database variable in main.js is ONLY available within the module scope of main.js where you imported it. If you want it available in webscraper.js, then you need to import it there too or pass it in as an argument. Every module must import the things it needs. This allows modules to explicitly name their dependencies, makes them easier to share or reuse and makes them easier to test. This practice encourage, "good module design".

In your specific case, you may want/need to pass the `database` instance to your `scrape()` function so it can use the one you've already initialized.

Here's one way to solve that issue (by passing the `database` instance to the `scrape()` function as an argument):

```
// main.js
var database = require('./src/database.js');
var webscraper = require('./src/webscraper.js');

database.init().then(()=> {
    webscraper.scrape(database);
});

// webscraper.js
exports.scrape = function(database) {
    // Find where we left off
    database.connection.query('SELECT `last_searched` FROM `post_index` WHERE `id` = 0', function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats good to know, however, I'm confused as this doesn't seem to be the case in my Electron application (as opposed to the Node.js script). Is there any way to stop that behavior in Electron as having every variable accessibe makes it very easy to take shortcuts?

Comment: @BoneJones - Are you using some sort of bundler when building your electron app.  I'm not an electron expert, but it supports regular node.js modules so if you're building it properly, you should be able to use regular node.js modules just fine.

Comment: @BoneJones - Are you using webPack with your Electron code to bundle it all into one larger file?

Comment: No. As for passing the variables in the Node.js script, is there a cleaner way I can do it besides passing the variables in every function call, for example, passing the database variable when webscraper is required?

Comment: @BoneJones - Yes, it could be passed as part of the module initialization and saved as long as the module was only being used/initialized by one other module.